# how can I validate value in text box using zend form?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am using zend. I have taken the code from models/form/settings.php

```
$top_menu_font_sizeNotEmpty = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
$top_menu_font_sizeNotEmpty->setMessage('Please enter top menu font size.');

$top_menu_font_size = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('top_menu_font_size', array(
      'label' => 'Top Menu Font Size :',
      'class' => 'text-size password',
      'value'=> $data[0]['top_menu_font_size'],
      'cols'  => '35',
      'rows'  =>'4',
      'required' => true,
      'validators' => array(
            array($top_menu_font_sizeNotEmpty, true),                                
      ),
  'decorators' => $this->requiredElementDecorators,
  'description' => '<p>Font Size should have the value between 10 - 15</p>',
    ));
    $this->addElement($top_menu_font_size);
```

From the above text box, I want to validate the text box having number between 10 - 15 only.
How can I validate value in zend form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$top_menu_font_size->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Between(array('min' => 10, 'max' => 15)););`